# Extending a basic rectangle deck out 4’

Tags: deck, safety, extension

We have a basic porch deck that is a rectangle with stairs at the front of it. We want to extend the deck out 4’. We’re only adding on to the area to the right of the steps, so we’d be building an area about 6’ long and 4’ wide. We’d like to piggy back off the joist (is that the correct term?) and put two posts in at the other side of the extension to frame it in on all sides. VERY basic.

Can we attach a new joist on to the old one and frame it out from there? Do we need to stabilize that? What special things do we need to think about to make sure it’s safe and sturdy? This is to accommodate patio furniture and provide more walking room as it’s the main area we sit outside, as well as, enter the home.

It is not going to be covered and will have basic railing. No stairs off of this new area. If you can’t tell, I’m planning this myself and will get help with building it but I don’t want to hire anyone and keeping it small prevents me from needing permits.

Any reference to another website with instructions or just a list of what I might need and do would be appreciated. I need to keep it inexpensive. I’ve done a lot of research, but want to be sure I’m covering all the details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answers depend on the details of the current rim joist. Please provide photos or a diagram and details about attachment. Your question needs to be specific. Also, you don't do your sex any favors by implying that you're less capable as a woman. I've removed that cringe-worthy bit from your post out of respect for all the female DIYers in the world.

Comment: "keeping it small prevents me from needing permits" in some jurisdiction it's not just size but (also) height that determines whether you need permits. Please provide a detailed sketch as mentioned in the above comment too, and include dimensions, points of support, and heights.

Comment: In general, use the same size as the existing joist and the post for the expansion. Lay the new joists in the same direction as the existing ones, and attach the edge joists to the existing rim beam using connection hardware. The deck should be sloped toward the street, and the posts should be placed on sturdy foundations. Check with the experienced local contractor, as they usually know whether a permit is required or not for this type of works.

Comment: "keeping it small prevents me from needing permits" As P2000 already noted, that is not necessarily the case. Decks *specifically* often need permits where other comparable work (e.g., building a small freestanding shed) might not. That is because [deck problems can be really serious](https://bethesdamagazine.com/bethesda-beat/police-fire/three-trapped-two-injured-in-rockville-deck-collapse/), sometimes fatal. Doing some advance research here to figure out what *might* work is a good idea. But check your local rules to find out specific guidelines and determine if/when you need a permit.